# Using UPDATE, INNER JOIN, MAX and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join

I have a table course that I would like to copy data into from 2 other tables, venue and lesson.

A course can be linked to 1 venue and can have many lessons.

I want to set the course end date based on the last lesson date.

Currently I have the following code but it doesn't work with my GROUP BY statement.

```
UPDATE course AS c
INNER JOIN venue as v.id = c.venue_id
INNER JOIN lesson l ON c.id = l.course_id
   SET
     c.venue_name = v.name,
     c.end_date = MAX(l.date)
WHERE c.status IS NULL
GROUP BY l.course_id
```

Is the following a suitable and valid approach?

```
UPDATE course AS c
INNER JOIN venue as v.id = c.venue_id
   SET
     c.venue_name = v.name,
     c.end_date = (SELECT MAX(l.date) FROM lesson INNER JOIN lesson l ON c.id = l.course_id GROUP BY l.course_id)
WHERE c.status IS NULL
```

Comment: It will work, but depending on the size of the table, it might be quite slow